# Boolean comparison of ints when RHS == Integer.MAX_VALUE, why does this loop terminate?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to work out why this loop terminates...

```
@Test
public void test() {

    int counter=0;
    int from = 0;
    int until = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while(counter <= until) {
        counter++;
        if(counter < from) {
            System.out.println("continuing " + counter + " <= " + from);
            continue;
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("finished " + counter);
}
```

`while(counter <= until)` should always resolve to `true` because the counter cannot be increased beyond Integer.MAX_VALUE. Thus, the loop should not terminate.

However, in Eclipse, if I run with the JUnit runner I get:

```
finished 108772
```

If I run in the debugger I get:

```
finished 125156
```

The output in the `if(counter < from)` is never output. If I remove that block the code still terminates, this time at Integer.MAX_VALUE.

```
finished 2147483647
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to terminate.  An `int` is always `<= Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: It terminates with `int until = Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;`

Comment: This is very strange. For me it gives inconsistent values around 300000 most of the time. I think it must be a compiler optimisation of some kind, because it certainly should not terminate. Looking into it now...

Comment: Works as expected in Java 7, when tested from the command line, but fails with Java 6. Quite odd.

Comment: I've had a look at the bytecode and it is as expected. I think the weirdness must be a runtime optimisation, and I don't think I can help much with that.

Comment: the loop is an infinite loop because every integer value is less than or equal to Integer.MAX_INT.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Good point, and I'm embarrassed to have not spotted this myself. That said, it *does* terminate, so I'm going to change the question to that effect... _why_ does it terminate?

Comment: Possible? Looks definite to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what you are trying to do here your while loop will work as expected but the from will never change so the "counter less than from" wont ever be executed?

until (max int) will be = 2147483647

if you change the while loop to (counter < until) you get the output text of "finished 2147483647"

that help?

Comment: Yeah, that block is never executed, but strangely removing it changes the behaviour (see updated question above). The block *does* terminate.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your output so this is not an answer, just an observation. Consider just these lines.

```
int counter=0;
int until = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
while(counter <= until) {
    counter++;
```

The while condition is 'less than or EQUAL'.  So when counter is equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE one is added to it.  This produces the largest possible Java negative number.  Keep adding one to this value and it will eventually become zero, then count up once again until  it reaches Integer.MAX_VALUE.  Then the whole sequence starts over again. It looks like an infinite loop to me.

You would also execute the 'continuing' line on each iteration while counting up from the largest negative number.

Comment: Agreed - you probably posted just before/after I edited the question to ask specifically "why does this terminate?".